# Route that points to a controller in a different module

Tags: angularjs

How can I point to a controller that belongs to a different module: 
I need something like this, although this approach apparently doesn't work

```
controllers = angular.module "controllers",[]
controller.indexCtrl = ($scope) ->
   console.log "inside index"

app = angular.module "app",["ngRoute","controllers"]
app.config ["$routeProvider", ($routeProvider)->
    $routeProvider.when "/",
    templateUrl: "templates/index.html"
    controller: "controllers.indexCtrl"
]
```

Note: let's say I don't have direct access to the controller function. (Maybe it sits in a different file). I need to get to it though its module